# The sum over all irreducible characters of an element of an abelian group is $0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, abelian-groups, characters

This seems like a very fundamental thing, yet I simply cannot prove it. I have some ideas, but need help fleshing them out.

I want to prove:

> Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, and let $G^\star$ be the set of all irreducible characters of $G$. Then, if $g\in G$ is not the identity, we have:
>
> $$\sum\limits_{\chi\in G^\star}\chi(g)=0.$$

For what it is worth, everyone I've talked to has mentioned the row and column orthogonality relations for character tables, yet those are no real help here, as they require that I take inner products, and I have no way to manipulate this so that every character gets paired with itself. The only hint in the text is to multiply by $\chi'(g)$, where $\chi'\in G^\star$ and $\chi(g)\neq 1$.

This leads me to believe I must manipulate somehow to get this:

$$\chi'(g)\sum\limits_{\chi\in G^\star}\chi(g)\stackrel{?}=\sum\limits_{\chi\in G^\star}\chi(g),$$

which of course would give the result. But how do I do this? I know that since $G$ is abelian, all elements of $G^\star$ have degree $1$, so let's write:

$$\chi'(g)\sum\limits_{\chi\in G^\star}\chi(g)=\sum\limits_{\chi\in G^\star}\chi'(g)\chi(g),$$

which looks awfully like it will just amount to a reindexing of the sum to give the result I put with a question mark, but I have no idea how to justify that claim. That's what I need help with, I think. Or I need somebody to tell me I am barking up the wrong tree. Or something.

Comment: I wish the downvoter would explain how this question possibly deserves a downvote...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing something very important: $G^{\ast}$, the set of group homorphisms $G\to\mathbb{C}^{\times}$, is a group under pointwise multiplication. That is, if $\chi$ and $\chi'$ are homomorphisms, then so too is their product $\chi\cdot\chi'$. It is easy to verify:

$$ \begin{array}{ll} (\chi\cdot\chi')(gh) & =\chi(gh)\chi'(gh) \\ & =\chi(g)\chi(h)\chi'(g)\chi'(h) \\ & =\chi(g)\chi'(g)\chi(h)\chi'(h) \\ & = (\chi\cdot\chi')(g)~(\chi\cdot\chi')(h). \end{array} $$

Therefore, multiplying $S=\sum_{\chi\in G^{\ast}}\chi(g)$ by $\chi'(g)$ doesn't actually change the value of $S$. But if we have $\chi'$ such that $\chi'(g)\ne1$, then how can multiplying $S$ by positive number besides $1$ not change its value? Only if $S=0$. (How you know there is a $\chi'\in G^{\ast}$ such that $\chi'(g)\ne1$ is another matter.)

Comment: Thanks very much. I am only now getting used to using character theory in my work, and while I recall now that the set of irreducible characters is indeed a group, I had forgotten it, as you noted. I do know how to show that the character $\chi'$ exists, at least. At least I came close!

Comment: I think you forgot a really important thing to say: you didn't use the fact that G is abelian! I think that an important point is that the characters are homomorphisms only if the representation is one-dimensional which is the case if the representation is an irriducible representation of an abelian group.

Comment: @Dac0 Indeed. This was in my original comment, but in my answer I decided to just let $G^{\ast}$ be the set of homomorphisms. (Essentially, it will be the dual of the abelianization, in which case the claim is true as long as $G^{\ast}$ isn't trivial, i.e. as long as $G$ isn't perfect.)

Comment: Ah ok! I didn't notice that. Thank you

Comment: @Dac0 Thankfully I already knew that, but thanks for pointing it out for anyone that comes along later!